# NGX-Bootstrap Datepicker when i open it on my ipad its not selecting the date on first click

Tags: datepicker, angular7, ngx-bootstrap

I am using NGX-Bootstrap DatePicker
When i open it in tab or mobile (all the devices other than desktop and laptop).I need to tap on the Date two times to select. How to resolve this problem

For Demo please open (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) in TAB or MOBILE

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem yesterday. This is a Apple devices issue and happens because it device detect the user's first touch like a hover, instead of a click.

To solve this, im using a event inside the input that im calling the ngx-bootstrap datepicker to execute a method when calendar is shown , like:

```
<input type="text" bsDaterangepicker  (onShown)="onShowPicker($event)">
```

and inside the method onShownPicker, my algorithm is detecting if the user is inside an apple device and then, it use a ngxbootstrap-datepicker method to instance dayHandler (that is called when click is normally detected, instead of hover):

```
onShowPicker(event) {
    const dayHoverHandler = event.dayHoverHandler;
    const hoverWrapper = (hoverEvent) => {
        const { cell, isHovered } = hoverEvent;

        if ((isHovered &&
          !!navigator.platform &&
          /iPad|iPhone|iPod|Apple/.test(navigator.platform)) &&
          'ontouchstart' in window
        ) {
            (this.datapickerDirective as any)._datepickerRef.instance.daySelectHandler(cell);
        }

        return dayHoverHandler(hoverEvent);
    };
    event.dayHoverHandler = hoverWrapper;
}
```

To work properly, you need to have the datepicker directive as viewChild because its used on this method above. in my case, im using like:

```
@ViewChild(BsDaterangepickerDirective, {static: false}) datapickerDirective;
```